# Adding Static Resources inside Contol.Resources Tag?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing an application that allows me to leverage the default template selector provided by a ListBox.  Currently, I am defining the DataTemplates within the Listbox.Resources tag like so:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Dog}">
         // Some XAML here
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Cat}">
         // Some XAML here
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.Resources>
```

The problem is that these Templates can get rather lengthy.  I know this is probably trivial, but how can I reference these Datatemplates from a ResourceDictionary that has been added to the XAML file without writing a template selector? I can't seem to find documentation for doing this anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing it in a resource dictionary, why not create a composite control(s) which would achieve easier reading in the datatemplates as well as centralize the xaml into a named entity control. Plus one could add any dependency properties which would help with the data transfer.